# C - Send input from Parent to Child and return it back

Tags: c, pipe, parent-child

So, I'm pretty new to C programming language and I'm having some difficulty completing this exercise.
Basically, I have to fork(), then send an input string from Parent process to Child, do an uppercase function in the Child process and return it to Parent so it can print.

The pipes are still really "gibberish" but disregarding the uppercase function, I've got this:

````
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define READ_END   0
#define WRITE_END  1
#define BUF_SIZE   256

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int   fd[2];
  pid_t pid;

  if (pipe(fd) < 0) {
    perror("pipe error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
    perror("fork error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } 
  else
  if (pid > 0) {
    int nbytes;
    char line[BUF_SIZE];    

    /* parent writes to pipe */
    close(fd[READ_END]);
    snprintf(line, BUF_SIZE,
         "Hello child (%d)!  I'm your parent pid (%d).\n",
         pid, getpid());
    if ((nbytes = write(fd[WRITE_END], line, strlen(line))) < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to write to pipe: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    close(fd[WRITE_END]);
    
    /* wait for child and exit */
    if ( waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to catch child exiting: %s\n", strerror(errno));       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);     
    }

    /* return gracefully */
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  } 
  else {
    int  nbytes;
    char line[BUF_SIZE];
    
    /* child reads from pipe */
    close(fd[WRITE_END]);
    if ((nbytes = read(fd[READ_END], line, BUF_SIZE)) < 0 ) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read from pipe: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);     
    }
    close(fd[READ_END]);

    /* write message from parent */
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, line, nbytes);

    /* return gracefully */
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
}```
````

Comment: I would argue that you're doing it the wrong way around. Let the *child* to the processing, and send the result to the *parent*. Then the *parent* writes the output to the terminal.

Comment: Ass for your problem I would suggest you step through the parent code in a debugger to make sure it does what it's supposed to do. Then to the same with the child process.